# Can I find out which iOS apps are no longer available in the App Store?

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

I have hundreds of apps installed on my iOS device. I've noticed that some of those apps do not appear to be in the App Store any longer.

Is there a way to quickly identify which apps I have installed, that are no longer available in the App Store? I'd like to be able to decide which ones I feel like keeping, in an effort to tidy up my device.

(Other than manually searching the store for each one, of course.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way of knowing that Apple offers.

I'm not aware of any jailbreak apps that can do this, either.